# get last date in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i show you my logic is getting error only when month is **December**

```
declare @startDate datetime      
declare @endDate datetime 

set @startDate = convert(varchar(2),@month)+'/1/'+ convert(varchar(4),@year)      

set @endDate =  dateadd(DD,-1,(convert(varchar(2),@month+1)+'/1/'+convert(varchar(4),@year))) 

while(@startDate < @endDate+1)      
begin      
  insert into @tempday      
  select @startDate      
  set @startDate = dateadd(day, 1, @startDate )      
end
```

please help

Comment: Why is this titled "plsql" but tagged sql-server-2008?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have `@startdate`, use:

```
set @enddate = dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,@startdate))
```

And I don't think you mean plsql...

There are other things you could think about too, such as not using a while-loop. Why not query a table that has plenty of rows (such as `sys.all_columns`) and use:

```
insert @tempday
select top (datediff(day,@startdate,@enddate)+1) 
  dateadd(day,row_number() over (order by (select 1))-1,@startdate)
from sys.all_columns;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of December `@month+1` will get you 13 which is not a valid month number

Comment: so what shoud i do bro

Comment: i have stored procedure it works fine with all month but in December i get this error

Comment: if you want to go with your code then iif(@month=12, 1, @month+1)

Comment: mind you there are other ways to get the list of days, probably more efficient